# Cast real type to boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query which should change field type from real to boolean:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN test_flag TYPE boolean USING test_flag::boolean;
```

but it fails with error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type real to boolean
LINE 1: ...st_flag TYPE boolean USING test_flag::boolean;
```

Comment: How do you decide which `REAL` values represent `TRUE` and `FALSE` boolean values?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different `USING` clause to convert the data:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table
   ALTER COLUMN test_flag TYPE boolean USING (test_flag <> 0.0);
```